# How to insert multiple text input data with checkbox in laravel?

Tags: laravel-9

Basically I want to insert into database the data according to input value. I have multiple checkbox and input field. When I store data only " A " then its working and  others are null values. If I stored others with A then stored all the values. User can be check and input values  any time and any number of check box.
Here are the code snippet,

```
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="txt_check[]" id="">A
    <label for="fname">Win1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_win[]"><br><br>
    <label for="fname">Win2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_loss[]"><br><br>
    <label for="fname">Win3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_draw[]"><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="txt_check[]" id="">B
    <label for="lname">Loss1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_win[]"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Loss2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_loss[]"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Loss3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_draw[]"><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="txt_check[]" id="">C
    <label for="lname">Draw1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_win[]"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Draw2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_loss[]"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Draw3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txt_draw[]"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
       $win = $request->txt_win;
        $loss = $request->txt_loss;
        $draw = $request->txt_draw;
        $checkValue =  $request->txt_check ;
foreach $checkValue as $key => $value) {

$result[] = Model::create([
                    
     'checkValue' => $value, 
     'winning' => $win [$key],
     'lost' => $loss [$key],
     'draw' => $draw [$key],
                   
         ]);
   }
```

This code works well for the first insert but when I try to second insert then insert null value like this-

I want to insert into database this way,

```
 checkval  win  loss  draw
       A       2    3     4
       B       3    4     3
       C       4    5     5
```

How can I do this. I need help. Advanced thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a circular brace on the foreach loop.

Change this

```
foreach $checkValue as $key => $value) {
     $result[] = Model::create([
                    
     'checkValue' => $value, 
     'winning' => $win [$key],
     'lost' => $loss [$key],
     'draw' => $draw [$key],
      ]);
   }
```

to this

```
foreach ($checkValue as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = Model::create([
                    
     'checkValue' => $value, 
     'winning' => $win [$key],
     'lost' => $loss [$key],
     'draw' => $draw [$key],
     ]);
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't working . Still insert null value. If I select 2 checkbox  only checkbox value inserted but others value null.

Comment: Remove the id on your elements. You have the same id duplicating on the page.

Comment: removed all the ids  from the  text input field but same  nothing change at all.

Comment: If I use "Json_encode" then outcomes like this -
 A  ["2","3","null"]
 B  ["2","3","null"]

Its look like - if I select first 2 box then 3rd box value inserted as null.

Comment: I am unable to locate where the error might be arising from at this point.

Comment: I found that,  into the  foreach loop $key  is null.  but out of the loop  $win , $loss and $draw  show  value , test it by " dd " . I can't find the reason.  Whatever, thank you  so much for your time.